# jQuery selector + variable target match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="text" id="sname">
<input type="text" id="email">
<input type="tel" id="phone">
<select id="status">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

...

<div id="output_fname"></div>
<div id="output_sname"></div>
<div id="output_email"></div>
<div id="output_phone"></div>
<div id="output_status"></div>
```

*Request*:
Please help me figure out how to pass all the values from `input, select, etc.. (what might show up in a form)` into a "preview" (in this case - into the div's).

PS:
I have tried this *(force me to paste the script numbers of times i have inputs and matching output_ divs - at least with my knowledge today)*:

```
$("#fname").on("focusout",function(){
    setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
         $("#output_fname").text(this.value);
    },this),10);
});
```

But is there a possibility to do something like:

```
<input type="text" class="grab-val" id="fname">
```

and then:

```
.val() from (all inputs)
.this class="grab-val" and 
send to (output_ + matching id)........ //something like that
```

**OR** (sorry for all the back and forward, but with this question I want to solve a problem but I also kindly ask for a lesson...)

What would a good solution be to create a preview on submit - before sending data into db. 
Data sent after a "is-the-data-correct-"-submit-button.

Comment: why dont you just make a duplicated form with all the divs properly layout and then when you enter the preview mode just copy all the values into the new form and hide the old one...

Comment: True - but please help me with the passing all the data to the "new" hidden form... you mean like: preview.php and $_POST... echo into new form??

Comment: well..time for you to learn some javascript. just do a foreach loop thru the dom element by name and its dam easy

Comment: haha, brilliant @Steve - javascript; thats exactly what i wanted to learn. As i said in the post: "with this question I want to solve a problem but I also kindly ask for a lesson..."

Comment: Please post the darn easy "foreach loop thru the dom element by name"

Comment: someone already done so and i think it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just give your preview divs a class of "preview"

```
<div class="preview" id="output_fname"></div>
<div class="preview" id="output_sname"></div>
<div class="preview" id="output_email"></div>
<div class="preview" id="output_phone"></div>
<div class="preview" id="output_status"></div>
```

Then on the preview button submit

```
$('.preview').text(function(){
     return $('#' + this.id.replace('output_','')).val();
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I can se in the script how the values are being posted to correct div (selector + variable match - great)! But describe the: "Then on the preview button submit".... show me the full script - please

Comment: @mikswe I think that he assumed you wanted the preview to appear when the form gets submitted. It seems like you actually want it when focus leaves a text field, so it would go inside your focusout method in your example (but you probably want to change it so it does focusout on any input field, instead of just fname)

Comment: @Katana314 - I'd just tried the submit solution above. Works like a charm! But true as you say - by putting the focusout method with the return $('#' + this.id.replace('output_','')).val(); i'll get the dynamic result - am i right??

Comment: @mikswe In the root context, what would the `this` object be? I think you just need to get a better sense of JQuery's selectors - For instance, this one: `$("form#myForm input").on("focusout", function() ...` would do the same focusout method for all inputs.

Comment: Ah - yes, on the inside of that function, you would need to dynamically get the correct ID selector. I missed where that was applying.

Comment: @Katana314 - it works! If i want the output val to fadeIn - where would you put that?

Answer (score 0):

I've created two JS Fiddles:

This one updates the preview realtime: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisBerragan/zcspmfmd/5/

..and this displays the preview on submit: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisBerragan/ub3y4ycj/15/

The realtime one has a function to bind the value of the registered input id to the text of the registered target id:

```
function bindToElement(sourceElement, targetElement) {
    var source = jQuery('#' + sourceElement),
        sourceType = source[0].tagName,
        target = jQuery('#' + targetElement);

    switch (sourceType) {
        case 'INPUT':
            source.on('keyup', function (event) {
                var sourceValue = event.target.value;
                target.text(sourceValue);
            });
            break;
        case 'SELECT':
            target.text(source.val());
            source.on('change', function (event) {
                var sourceValue = event.target.value;
                target.text(sourceValue);
            });
            break;
    }
}
bindToElement('fname', 'output_fname');
bindToElement('sname', 'output_sname');
bindToElement('email', 'output_email');
bindToElement('phone', 'output_phone');
bindToElement('status', 'output_status');
```

.. but a simple loop would allow you to save the repetition.

The preview on submit version has a function to convert a form into a previewable form - you simply provide the function with the formId and the previewAreaId and when the preview button is click it runs a showPreview function that finds every element in the form that is an input or a select and that isn't an input type 'button' and creates a div in the preview area with the value and adds a submit button to the form to confirm:

```
function previewOnSubmit (formId, previewAreaId) {
    var form = jQuery('#' + formId),
        previewButton = jQuery('#previewFormButton'),
        formInputs = form.children().filter(function (index, element) {
            var tag = element.tagName,
                inputType = jQuery(element).attr('type'),
                tagIsValidInput = (tag === 'INPUT' && inputType !== 'button') || tag === 'SELECT';
            return tagIsValidInput;
        }),
        preview = jQuery('#' + previewAreaId);

    function showPreview () {
        var confirmationButton = jQuery('<input type="submit" value="Confirm" />');
        preview.empty();
        jQuery.each(formInputs, function (index, element) {
            var value = element.value,
                inputPreview = jQuery('<div>' + value + '</div>');
            preview.append(inputPreview);
        });
        form.append(confirmationButton);
    }

    previewButton.on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        showPreview();
    });
}

previewOnSubmit('myForm', 'myFormPreview');
```

Hope these help!